# How to handle Pseudoreplication - Aggregate observations per group for linear mixed model or take individual observations

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, pseudorepliction

I´m trying to fit a linear mixed model to test if my dependent variable (B) is different between my treatments (A with 2 levels A&B). The study was conducted at severals sampling sites. To account for the paired data (measurements within one site) I would take sampling site as random effect into the model:

`lmer(B ~ A + (1|Site))`

However, to also account for the varibailty within each treamtent, serveral measurements were taken per site per treatment (i.e. field replicats, or pseudoreplicates, not the same number per treatment, as treatment B is expected to have a higher variabilty than treatment A).
I now wonder if I need to aggregate my data first and take the mean value over the pseudoreplicates (for each treatment for each site) as dependent variable or every single observation? Or as a third option include some nested structure into the random effect to account for the field replicates.

My data looks something like this:

| Site | Treatment A | Observation | Measurement B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 5.3 |
| 1 | A | 2 | 5.3 |
| 1 | A | 3 | 8.1 |
| 1 | B | 1 | 7.2 |
| 1 | B | 2 | 5.2 |
| 2 | A | 1 | 2.6 |
| 2 | A | 2 | 3.3 |
| 2 | A | 3 | 1.3 |
| 2 | B | 1 | 4.1 |
| 2 | B | 2 | 6.3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend aggregation as it would not allow you to account for within-treatment variability and would likely lose information about the variability of measurements, reducing statistical power.

I would rather suggest a model with nested random effects, where you account for the fact that observations are nested within treatments, which are in turn nested within sites. This model could look something like `lmer(B ~ A + (1|Site/Treatment))`, assuming that Treatment is nested within Site. This captures the variability at both the site level and the treatment level within each site. The notation `(1|Site/Treatment)` indicates that both site and treatment are random effects, with treatment nested within site.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer - much appreciated! I didn't realise that I could simply nest treatment in site, but thought I had to recode observation. Just one follow-up question. To get an understanding about possible explanatory variables for the treatment differences between sites, I want to include further effects in the model (mostly environmental variables, like e.g. precipitation). My model would then look something like:  lmer (B~Treatment+Precipitation+(1|Site/Treatment). Precipitation is just given once per site. So do I then just repeat the same Precipitation value within each row?

Comment: Hi Julia you are very welcome. Yes, what you just wrote makes sense. It would be an upper level (Site level) variable. Thanks for accepting my answer.